# How to waitFor when page refreshes in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have an app I'm working with that is behaving like this... You visit a url `/refresh`, and it loads the page with a loader/spinner/bar showing for like 5 seconds, then it refreshes the page after it's done. It does this so it can load the latest data that was computed during `/refresh`.

Right now I am just setting a timeout longer than the loader will *most likely* stay around, but this is brittle because a bad network connection could put it over the line.

How can I instead "watch" for when the refresh happens? What technique would you recommend. It seems to start to get hairy pretty fast.

Into the nitty gritty, when the loader is showing, when it finishes it is gone for like a half a second *before* the page reload. So I can't just wait til the loader is gone. It seems like I need to keep some sort of state variable around in the DOM like in `localStorage`, but can't pinpoint it. Would love some help.

Answer (score 0):

well you could "watch" for the element that display the data using [page.$(selector)](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector), or if no such element you could also wait for the specific request 's response:

```
const waitForResponse = (page, url) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        page.on("response", function callback(response){
            if (response.url() === url) {
                resolve(response);
                page.removeListener("response",callback)
            }
        })
    })
};

const res = await waitForResponse(page,"url of the request you want to wait for");
```

[Wait for Network request before continuing process](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3649)